# Please remove the unneeded options when flagging your own posts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, flags

I love the new flag dialog.

However,

- when you flag your own question, the "low quality" option is available, and
- when you flag your own answer, both the "low quality" and "not an answer" options are available

While it would be nice to have users flag their own low quality posts, it's pretty unlikely, so these options should be removed.

[image: Just think how much smaller this image could be without those unnecessary options!]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good idea, I just checked this in!